# How can pass variable to a template and receive variable in beego

Tags: templates, go, beego, go-templates

My template file:

```
{{range $index, $option := .alternatives}}
<div id="splashAlternative{{$index}}" class="col-sm-2">
    <select id="flashSrc_{{$index}}">
    {{template "alternative_src.html" $option}}
    </select>
</div>
{{end}}
```

I want pass `$option` to template, and `alternative_src.html` code :

```
{{if compare .option ""}}
  <option value="" selected="selected">
  </option>
{{else}}
  <option value=""></option>
{{end}}
{{if compare .option "xxx"}}
  <option value="xxx" selected="selected">xxx</option>
{{else}}
  <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
{{end}}
```

but I get problem below:

```
executing "alternative_src.html" at <.option>: can't evaluate field option in type string
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `{{template}}` action and you pass something, that becomes the dot `.` in the called template. Quoting from the package doc of [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

```
{{template "name" pipeline}}
    The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
    to the value of the pipeline.
```

So inside `alternative_src.html` refer to the option only as a dot `.` (the dot `.` will mean the value of the pipeline you passed to the template, which is `$option` in the caller template):

```
{{if compare . ""}}
  <option value="" selected="selected">
  </option>
{{else}}
  <option value=""></option>
{{end}}
{{if compare . "xxx"}}
  <option value="xxx" selected="selected">xxx</option>
{{else}}
  <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
{{end}}
```